# On click add class to child element without Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a task where Jquery is not working, so I need a workaround to perform an add class event to child element of a div upon click event.
How do I go about that.
The Jquery for that purpose would be

```js
$('.wpb_vc_column').click(function(e) {
  alert();
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).find('.vc_controls').addClass('show-controls');
});
```

```css
.show-controls {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wpb_vc_column">
  <div class="vc_controls">SomeThing</div>
</div>
```

Its basically a wordpress backend thing which need to be workable on mobile devices.

Regards

Comment: I copy paste the source just adding the `e` and it looks ok

Comment: No I cannot use Jquery, I m working on a plugin called "Visual Composer" in the backend of wordpress pages. and Jquery is not supported there. so I need to do this via plain JS only

Comment: Consider adding that information to the question, otherwise it reads like you want to use jQuery but can't make it work, in which case the answer is either use plain JavaScript (as you want) or making jQuery work (which you don't).

Comment: wordpress does suppport jquery. you need to use `jQuery ` instead of `$`. try below code
`jQuery ('.wpb_vc_column').click(function(e) {
  alert();
  e.preventDefault();
  jQuery (this).find('.vc_controls').addClass('show-controls');
});`

or you can wrap your function in anonymous functoin 

`(function($) {
 
 // $ Works! You can test it with next line if you like
 // console.log($);
 
})( jQuery );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll()` to select all the elements with class `wpb_vc_column` and associate the click event to each element. Then click on these element will find the child elements with class `vc_controls` and add the class to it.

```js
function clickedColumn(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(this.querySelector('.vc_controls')){
      this.classList.add('show-controls');
    }
}
document.querySelectorAll('.wpb_vc_column').forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('click', clickedColumn);
});
```

```css
.show-controls{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpb_vc_column">
  <div class="vc_controls">SomeThing 1</div>
  <div class="vc_controls">SomeThing 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var myEle = document.getElementsByClassName('vc_controls');
myEle.className = "show-controls";
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection (a live NodeList, I believe), which has no `className` property.

Comment: @DavidThomas - there is one more issue it search under document , and OP wants to search under particular element

Comment: @DavidThomas I will create a fiddler for you

Answer (score 1):

make use of [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method and and search for child in parent element

```
el.querySelector("#child").className = 'show-controls';
or  
el.querySelector('.vc_controls').className = 'show-controls';
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function changeClass(element){
var get_vc_controls=element.getElementsByClassName('vc_controls');
get_vc_controls[0].className='show-controls';
}
```

```css
.show-controls {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="wpb_vc_column" style="border:1px solid;" onclick="changeClass(this)">
  <div class="vc_controls">SomeThing</div>
</div>
```